# ExtJS5 - chart polar itemclick

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, charts, extjs5

I would like to listen for the "itemclick" event on a polar chart in ExtJS 5 (Pie series).

So I would listen to it in my controller in the "init" function and use the "control" method to add the listener. 
But when I try to click on the chart, nothing appends... I also tried adding it with "addListener" or "on"

Before in ExtJS 4, we had to listen to this event on the series, I tried it, but it's not better...

Have somebody a solution?

[Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.PolarChart-event-itemclick) the extJS 5 docs of polar chart.

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to set the listener on the chart itself, not the series...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.myPolarChart', {  
    ....    
    listeners: {
         itemclick: function(series, item, event, eOpts){

         }
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Your solution don't work like I said, [here a Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/74q) so you can test it your self

Comment: Precision: this fiddle doesn't work on the fiddle app of sencha, it's because chart are not supported yet. But if you download the zip you can try it yourself.